# How to call a function and dupe the return value in a SELECT query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've defined a function `CREATE_UUID()` to generate UUID.
I want to INSERT INTO...SELECT to copy a table but with two new columns with the same value.

```
INSERT INTO Table (id, uuid1, uuid2)
SELECT ROWID, CREATE_UUID(), CREATE_UUID()
FROM AnotherTable
```

But doing so will call the function twice with different values. How should I modify this query so that it won't have different values for two columns in the same row but does generate a new UUID for each row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variant 1.

```sql
INSERT INTO `Table` (id, uuid1, uuid2)
SELECT ROWID, generate_uuid.new_uuid, generate_uuid.new_uuid
FROM AnotherTable
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT CREATE_UUID() new_uuid ) generate_uuid
```

But if you insert a lot of rows then server may "optimize" the execution, and **all** rows may obtain **the same UUID**.

Variant 2.

```sql
INSERT INTO `Table` (id, uuid1, uuid2)
SELECT ROWID, new_uuid, new_uuid
FROM ( SELECT ROWID, CREATE_UUID() new_uuid 
       FROM AnotherTable ) source_data;
```

In this case server may, backward, call new generation **for each inserted value**.

Variant 3.

```sql
INSERT INTO `Table` (id, uuid1, uuid2)
SELECT ROWID, @new_uuid := CREATE_UUID(), @new_uuid
FROM AnotherTable;
```

Seems to be the most safe. But used user-defined variable assignment is deprecated.

This everything in one [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4082cc7521c7ec810b72dc993454b03c).

Comment: WOW that's amazing! Thanks!

Comment: @liux Remember - if you insert a lot of rows then server may "optimize" the execution, and **all** rows may obtain the same UUID. So this solution is safe for single row insertion only.

Comment: @liux The answer updated. Investigate the fiddle carefully.